# Differential equation $y' = -2x y+ e^{-x^2}\sin(x)$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone help me solve this equation?
$$y' = -2xy + e^{-x^2}\sin(x)$$

#### Progress

I have been trying to solve it with the method of integrating factor.  I get to the point where:  $$y'+2xy=e^{-x^2}\sin(x)$$ Then I multiply each with: $e^{x^2}$. So I'm left with
$$e^{x^2}y  = \int  e^{x^2} \sin(x)$$
But from here I'm not sure how I can integrate.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried? Did you notice that it is separable?

Comment: Hi! thanks for your response, you Are suposed to solve it with integrating method.

Comment: Here is an example: https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t34.0-12/10850395_10152825071310600_759075354_n.jpg?oh=411e4561d5baebb1d83cf9644e62659b&oe=5487BA83&__gda__=1418178130_856cd4c66bdd580d7d9b2cd934b37fa3

Comment: Still I don't understand the stemps in this example

Comment: Thankyou! but not really
I get to the pint where:

y'+2xy=e^(-x^2)*sin(x)
Then I multiply each with: e^(x^2)
So I'm left with:

Comment: y*e^(x^2) = integral(sinx*e^(x^2))

Comment: But from here I'm not sure how I can integrate it
I tried to pus e^u then dx=du/2x

Comment: Can you please explain what an error function is, or how i can solve it?

Answer (score 3):

When you multiply both sides of $y' + 2xy = e^{-x^2}\sin x$ by $e^{x^2}$, you should have gotten:

$e^{x^2}y' + 2xe^{x^2}y = \sin x$

$\dfrac{d}{dx}[e^{x^2}y] = \sin x$

(Note that the right hand side is $\sin x$ and not $e^{x^2}\sin x$.)

Fortunately, you can write the antiderivative of $\sin x$ without using the [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).